# Reset items in object to default value

Tags: javascript

Whats the best way to reset an object to default values?

If I have

```js
const state = {
  name: null,
  surname: null
 }
```

I have a function that modifies the state

```js
function mutate(name) { 
 state.name = name;
}
```

Now, I'd like to make a function that will reset everything that it's in `state` object to default value. Which is null. How can I do this?

Comment: Unless you have a copy of the old value and the key where it should go, you can't. If you're thinking of something like Redux, you don't mutate state but return a new object to represent the new state, i.e. you have two state objects now, one holding the old data, and the other the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const DEFAULT = { name: null, surname: null };
const resetToDefault = state => Object.assign(state, DEFAULT);

const state = { name: null, surname: null };
console.log(state);
state.name = 'name'; state.surname = 'surname';
console.log(state);
resetToDefault(state);
console.log(state);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a constant variable that is your default object of null values and then in your function make the state equal to your constant function.

```
const defaultState = {
    name: null,
    surname: null
}

function resetState(){
    state = defaultState
}
```